# Firing Journey Source Event from Smart Capture

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

Can I fire a Journey event from a Smart Capture form? My requirement is that I want to inject a contact into a journey as soon as he signs up using smart capture form.

Is there any AMPScript that can do this?

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the form is hosted within CloudPages, there is actually an Entry Event that deals with this use case specifically. I have yet to use it personally so I can't provide personal experience, but from the description it would fit your scenario perfectly.

[image]

Comment: Interesting !! I don't have cloud pages yet. Am using standard smart capture form

Answer (score 0):

At the time of launching Smart capture entry event in Journey builder last year, Only forms build in classic builder was acceptable as journey entry source